# Passing string from Delphi to C# returns null. However it works fine when I call the Delphi lib from Delphi. How to receive string from Delphi

Tags: c#, string, delphi, pchar, delphi.net

I am completely new to Delphi and have been trying to make a few DLLs for .NET.

What I want to achieve is to send and receive txt output from my DLLs.

Here's what I've done so far:

Delphi Library function:

```pascal
function DBConnet(inputStr: PChar; connStr: PChar): PAnsiChar; stdcall; export;
var
  conStr: string;
  s: string;
begin  
  inputStr := PChar('Hello from Delphi! How are you ' + inputStr + connStr);
  try
    Result := PAnsiChar(inputStr);    
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
      Result := 'exception';
    end;
  end;
end;

Exports
  DBConnet;

end.
```

Here's my caller function in Delphi:

```
function DBConnet(inputStr: PChar; connStr: PChar): PChar; stdcall; external 'NewLib.dll';

procedure TUseDLLForm.functionxClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: string;
  conStr: string;
  i: integer;
begin
  a := 'firstname';
  conStr := 'lastname';
  ShowMessage(DBConnet(pchar(a), pchar(conStr)));
end;
```

This works fine with Delphi to Delphi. But when I try to call it from C#, the output received is null.

Here's my C# code block:

```cs
[DllImport("NewLib.dll",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
        CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern void DBConnet(string inputString,  string 
connectionString, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out string dbStrObj);
```

And then in Main I call it this way:

```
DBConnet(inputString, connectionString, out dbStrObj);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The DLL code you have shown is NOT compatible with your C# code.

Your C# code is relying on [default `string` marshaling behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings) that your DLL is not conforming to.

A `string` is passed to a DLL as a `PWideChar` pointer by default (if you are using Delphi 2009+, `PChar` maps to `PWideChar`, otherwise it maps to `PAnsiChar` instead).

Also, your DLL function is returning a `PAnsiChar`, but the marshaller is expecting a `PWideChar` by default, since you did not apply a `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]` attribute on the DLL function declaration on the C# side.

But more importantly, when a DLL returns a pointer to memory that the marshaller then takes ownership of, the memory MUST be allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc()` or equivalent, as the marshaller frees the memory with `CoTaskMemFree()` by default (see [Memory management with the interop marshaler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior#memory-management-with-the-interop-marshaler)).

You are returning a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, however that memory is not allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc()`. In fact, the memory is actually managed by the Delphi compiler and gets freed automatically when the function exits.  So, you are actually returning an invalid pointer to C#.

In fact, you are not even returning the pointer to C#!  On the C# side, you have declared the DLL as having an `out` parameter, but there is no such parameter on the DLL side!

With all of that said, try something more like this instead:

DLL:

```pascal
// uncomment this if you are NOT using D2009+ ...
{
type
  UnicodeString = WideString;
}

function UnicodeStringToCoTaskMemStr(const s: UnicodeString): PWideChar;
var
  Size: Integer;
begin
  Size := (Length(s) + 1) * SizeOf(WideChar);
  Result := PWideChar(CoTaskMemAlloc(Size));
  if Result <> nil then
    Move(PWideChar(s)^, Result^, Size);
end;

function DBConnet(inputStr: PWideChar; connStr: PWideChar): PWideChar; stdcall; export;
var
  sInput: UnicodeString;
  sConn: UnicodeString;
begin  
  try
    sInput := inputStr;
    sConn := connStr;
    Result := UnicodeStringToCoTaskMemStr('Hello from Delphi! How are you ' + sInput + sConn);
  except
    Result := UnicodeStringToCoTaskMemStr('exception');
  end;
end;
```

Delphi app:

```pascal
function DBConnet(inputStr: PWideChar; connStr: PWideChar): PWideChar; stdcall; external 'NewLib.dll';

// uncomment this if you are NOT using D2009+ ...
{
type
  UnicodeString = WideString;
}

procedure TUseDLLForm.functionxClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: UnicodeString;
  conStr: UnicodeString;
  ret: PWideChar;
begin
  a := 'firstname';
  conStr := 'lastname';
  ret := DBConnet(PWideChar(a), PWideChar(conStr));
  if ret <> nil then
  begin
    try
      ShowMessage(ret);
    finally
      CoTaskMemFree(ret);
    end;
  end else
    ShowMessage('nil');
end;
```

C#:

```cs
[DllImport("NewLib.dll",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public static extern string DBConnet(string inputString, string connectionString);
```

Or, using an `out` parameter instead:

DLL:

```pascal
// uncomment this if you are NOT using D2009+ ...
{
type
  UnicodeString = WideString;
}

function UnicodeStringToCoTaskMemStr(const s: UnicodeString): PWideChar;
var
  Size: Integer;
begin
  Size := (Length(s) + 1) * SizeOf(WideChar);
  Result := PWideChar(CoTaskMemAlloc(Size));
  if Result <> nil then
    Move(PWideChar(s)^, Result^, Size);
end;

function DBConnet(inputStr: PWideChar; connStr: PWideChar; out outputStr: PWideChar): boolean; stdcall; export;
var
  sInput: UnicodeString;
  sConn: UnicodeString;
begin  
  Result := False;
  try
    sInput := inputStr;
    sConn := connStr;
    outputStr := UnicodeStringToCoTaskMemStr('Hello from Delphi! How are you ' + sInput + sConn);
    Result := outputStr <> nil;
  except
  end;
end;
```

Delphi app:

```pascal
function DBConnet(inputStr: PWideChar; connStr: PWideChar, out outputStr: PWideChar): boolean; stdcall; external 'NewLib.dll';

// uncomment this if you are NOT using D2009+ ...
{
type
  UnicodeString = WideString;
}

procedure TUseDLLForm.functionxClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: UnicodeString;
  conStr: UnicodeString;
  ret: PWideChar;
begin
  a := 'firstname';
  conStr := 'lastname';
  if DBConnet(PWideChar(a), PWideChar(conStr), ret) then
  begin
    try
      ShowMessage(ret);
    finally
      CoTaskMemFree(ret);
    end;
  end else
    ShowMessage('fail');
end;
```

C#:

```cs
[DllImport("NewLib.dll",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
public static extern bool DBConnet(string inputString, string connectionString,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out outputString string);
```

Alternatively, you can allocate the returned memory as a `BSTR` string instead of using `CoTaskMemAlloc()`, just be sure to marshal it as a `BSTR` on the C# side:

DLL:

```pascal
// uncomment this if you are NOT using D2009+ ...
{
type
  UnicodeString = WideString;
}

function DBConnet(inputStr: PWideChar; connStr: PWideChar): PWideChar; stdcall; export;
var
  sInput: UnicodeString;
  sConn: UnicodeString;
begin  
  try
    sInput := inputStr;
    sConn := connStr;
    // the RTL's StringToOleStr() function returns a BSTR...
    Result := StringToOleStr('Hello from Delphi! How are you ' + sInput + sConn);
  except
    Result := StringToOleStr('exception');
  end;
end;
```

Delphi app:

```pascal
function DBConnet(inputStr: PWideChar; connStr: PWideChar): PWideChar; stdcall; external 'NewLib.dll';

// uncomment this if you are NOT using D2009+ ...
{
type
  UnicodeString = WideString;
}

procedure TUseDLLForm.functionxClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: UnicodeString;
  conStr: UnicodeString;
  ret: WideString; // NOT UnicodeString!
begin
  a := 'firstname';
  conStr := 'lastname';
  Pointer(ret) := DBConnet(PWideChar(a), PWideChar(conStr));
  if ret <> '' then
    ShowMessage(ret)
  else
    ShowMessage('nil');
end;
```

C#:

```cs
[DllImport("NewLib.dll",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
public static extern string DBConnet(string inputString, string connectionString);
```

Or, using an `out` parameter:

DLL:

```pascal
// uncomment this if you are NOT using D2009+ ...
{
type
  UnicodeString = WideString;
}

function DBConnet(inputStr: PWideChar; connStr: PWideChar; out outputStr: WideString): boolean; stdcall; export;
var
  sInput: UnicodeString;
  sConn: UnicodeString;
begin  
  Result := False;
  try
    sInput := inputStr;
    sConn := connStr;
    outputStr := 'Hello from Delphi! How are you ' + sInput + sConn;
    Result := True;
  except
  end;
end;
```

Delphi app:

```pascal
function DBConnet(inputStr: PWideChar; connStr: PWideChar; out outputStr: WideString): boolean; stdcall; external 'NewLib.dll';

// uncomment this if you are NOT using D2009+ ...
{
type
  UnicodeString = WideString;
}

procedure TUseDLLForm.functionxClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: UnicodeString;
  conStr: UnicodeString;
  ret: WideString;
begin
  a := 'firstname';
  conStr := 'lastname';
  if DBConnet(PWideChar(a), PWideChar(conStr), ret) then
    ShowMessage(ret)
  else
    ShowMessage('fail');
end;
```

C#:

```cs
[DllImport("NewLib.dll",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
public static extern bool DBConnet(string inputString, string connectionString,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out string outputStr);
```

Comment: Thanks @Remy. It helped a lot and added to my learning. Thank you!