# How to use delphi dll in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport

I tried to call a dll that is coded in delphi in C#. (delphi 11 64bit)
I believe there will be some problems.
Therefore, I tried some example in these website:
[Calling a Delphi method in a dll from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601423/calling-a-delphi-method-in-a-dll-from-c-sharp)
[Calling a Delphi DLL from a C# .NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163364/calling-a-delphi-dll-from-a-c-sharp-net-application)

But there is no response, and the applicaiton closes.

These are my codes:

example 1

delphi

```
function DBConnect1(inputStr,connStr:PWideChar):PWideChar;stdcall;
begin
  try
     result:=PWideChar('Hello from Delphi!');
  except
     result:=PWideChar('Exception');
  end;
end;
```

C#

```
[DllImport("Project1.dll",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public static extern string DBConnect1(string inputString, string connectionString);

string inputString = "Parker";
string connectionString = "MyComputer";
string dbStrObj1 = DBConnect1(inputString, connectionString);
MessageBox.Show(dbStrObj1);
```

example 2

delphi

```
function Test1(sFD,sVD,sINI,sCh,sSD: string): PWideChar;stdcall;
var
  tempStr:string;
  str:WideString;
begin
  tempStr:=sFD+sVD+sINI+sCh+sSD;
  try
   result:= PWideChar(tempStr);
  except
    str:='Error';
    result:=PWideChar(str);
  end;
    result:=PWideChar(str);
end;
```

C#

```
[DllImport("Project1.dll", EntryPoint = "LoginLic", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public static extern string LoginLic(string s1, string s2, string s3, string s4, string s5);

string strId = "PCMS";
string strVersion = "AD19";
string strIni = @"";
string strCheck = "0";
string strSubDate = null;
string aa;
aa = UseDll.LoginLic(strId, strVersion, strIni, strCheck, strSubDate);
```

Comment: second one has mismatched function names. For the first one, no error message from C# runtime at all? Make sure you are matching 32/64 bit

Comment: note that sample explicitly says not to use string as a return type

Comment: Hi, pm100. Thanks a lot for your response.
First of all, I changed the platform targer to  64 bit in Build page. And solution platform is Any CPU. There is no response and no error message. Even, I used try-catch that still no response and the application closes.
Second, I changed solution platform to x64 and Platform target is x64. The error is DllNotFoundException. 


And sorry about that, I didn't change the name in this page. The name is LoginLic.

Comment: did you read my second comment tho

Comment: another suggestion, write a very simple function, say one that returns 42, get tha going and gradually add more argument and return types

Comment: Hi, pm100, I still need a return valut that is string. I would use this string to do something. Therefore, the string is essential.

Comment: I didn't understand your another suggestion. Would you explain it more details?

Comment: Hi pm100.
I tried a example today.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529623/passing-string-from-delphi-to-c-sharp-returns-null-however-it-works-fine-when-i
It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to marshall function parameters also. Refer this link for passing string with Marshalling https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshalling-for-strings

```
[DllImport("Project1.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public static extern string DBConnect1(MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string inputString, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string connectionString);
```

Comment: Hi Hari, thanks a lot for your reply.
I tried your suggestion and edit my code. But there is still no response.

Comment: You can try with BSTR. Both in delphi and C# input strings. I used to interop between C++ and C# with BSTR strings

Comment: Try to debug your code with native debugger. To enable native debugging Properties -> Debug -> Enable the check box "Enable Native Debugging' option

Comment: Hari, I tried your suggestion that is 'enable native debuggin'. I got a exception thrown which is my.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
And got a exception unhandled that detail is Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC961AF609 (ntdll.dll) in my.exe: 0xC0000374: parameters: 0x00007FFC962197F0

Comment: BTW, I call the dll and use that function to send the string to the server. That was a success. The server received the string I sent. But it still has the exception unhandled problem in C#.

Comment: Can you please specify the exception

Comment: Hari, since this is Chinese, it took me a while to understand how to explain it in English. This means "the stack around the variable is corrupted".

Comment: Then Change the calling convention to Cdel `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` and cdel in Delphi

Comment: Still can't. Getting the same issue...

Comment: Are you using BSTR strings or others ?

Comment: In Delphi, I tried input and return with 'widestring'. I tried UnmanagedType.BStr in C#, and I got AccessViolationException.
And I removed UnmanagedType.BStr, still get the samce exception: AccessViolationException.

Comment: try with integer or double values, if it works there is problem only on String Marshaling

Comment: Add new Method with single integer input and return the same input and try to print it on C# exe console

Comment: Hi, Hari, I tried integer and double, that all work well and get the correct value.
I tried it on winform, and show the value on the messagebox.
Only string make me very confused. I tried your suggestion debugging code in enable native debugging mode. It could get the value I want but doesn't work without native debugging mode.

Comment: Somehow you are marshaling string in wrong way that why you are getting Exception.

Comment: Can you share your delphi method here ?

Comment: Hi Harry.
May I have your personal contact information?
I could post the screenshot to you.

Comment: Here is a simple function in delphi:
function Getname(str1,str2,str3:string): PWideChar;stdcall ;
var
  total:string;
begin
  total:= 'str1:'+str1+',str2:'+str2+',str3:'+str3;
  result:=PWideChar('12348;asder');
  showmessage(total);
end;

Comment: Here is a code in C#:
[DllImport("Project1.dll",
           CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public static extern string Getname(
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string str1,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string str2,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string str3);

Comment: Hi, Hari
I tried a example today.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529623/passing-string-from-delphi-to-c-sharp-returns-null-however-it-works-fine-when-i
I would use this example to understand how to work.